# Loading JSON-L File

Tags: python, json

I have been trying to load the file in the format **'.json' with multiple lines** i.e. it has the following format(arbitrary data):

data.json :

{"John" : "doe", "Age" : "Unknown"}

{"kat" : "doe", "Age" : "Unknown"}

{"Brian" : "doe", "Age" : "Known"}

I have tried the following lines of code which doesn't seem to be working.

```
dt = []
with open("data.json") as file:
for line in file.readlines():
    temp = json.loads(line)
    dt.append(temp)
print(dt)
```

I keep getting an empty list.

Comment: Do you really have empty lines in between each line? And is your `for` loop block really not indented inside the `with` block? Because after removing the empty lines and fixing the indentation, your code seems to work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xREE.png

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working" is not a concrete error description. What does it do? What do you see? Please provide a [mcve] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, a json file can't have multiple objects without being inside of a list.
So you would have to firstly find a way to make the objects in the file within a list:

```json
[
    {"John" : "doe", "Age" : "Unknown"},
    {"kat" : "doe", "Age" : "Unknown"},
    {"Brian" : "doe", "Age" : "Known"}
]
```

Then your python wasn't too far off. Something like this would work:

```py
dt = []
with open('data.json') as file:
    for object in json.load(f):
        dt.append(object)
    file.close()

print(dt) # Output: [{'John': 'doe', 'Age': 'Unknown'}, {'kat': 'doe', 'Age': 'Unknown'}, {'Brian': 'doe', 'Age': 'Known'}]
```

Comment: You don't need `file.close` if you open it inside a context manager: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files: "*It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point.*"